# ORA-22288 when I try to insert data to table from xml

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm trying to insert entries in my USERS table from a xml file (that is on Desktop) with this :

```
CREATE DIRECTORY EXAMPLE_DIR AS 'C:\Users\user\Desktop';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXAMPLE_DIR TO PUBLIC;

INSERT INTO USERS (Id, Reputation, CreationDate, DisplayName, LastAccessDate, AboutMe, Views, UpVotes, DownVotes)
SELECT Id, Reputation, TO_TIMESTAMP(CreationDateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), DisplayName, TO_TIMESTAMP(LastAccessDateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), AboutMe, Views, UpVotes, DownVotes
  FROM XMLTABLE(
        '/users/row'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('EXAMPLE_DIR', 'Users.xml'), NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8'))
        COLUMNS
            Id INTEGER PATH '@Id',
            Reputation INTEGER PATH '@Reputation',
            CreationDateStr VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) PATH '@CreationDate',
            DisplayName VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@DisplayName',
            LastAccessDateStr VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) PATH '@LastAccessDate',
            AboutMe VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@AboutMe',
            Views INTEGER PATH '@Views',
            UpVotes INTEGER PATH '@UpVotes',
            DownVotes INTEGER PATH '@DownVotes',
            WebsiteUrl VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)  PATH '@WebsiteUrl',
            Location VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@Location',
            ProfileImageUrl VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@ProfileImageUrl',
            AccountId   INTEGER PATH '@AccountId'
    );
```

But even if the file have all permission on read and write, the console shows me this error

```
Error report -
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
Access is denied.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 296
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the database running on your PC too? The directory has to be on the DB server (or mounted/visible there), not on a separate client machine. If it is all one machine the Oracle account has to be able to see the file, so your own directory might not be appropriate.

Comment: yes, the server is running on my machine

Comment: @Loki00 check under which account your oracle service works, then move your file to any directory that is accessible for it.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I've tried to change my file directory but nothing changed :(

Comment: More details... Under which account does your oracle service work? Directory path? Directory and file permissions? Parent directories permissions?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I'm using ```SYS``` account for my oracle db. The file is now in my user root. The file has all the permission in oracle (as you can read in my insert in the question text) and even in my file property :(

Comment: From your code I see you are on Windows. Open Windows Services and check Oracle service - which account does it use?

Comment: Then create directory `C:\EXT` on your machine in windows, open its properties (Alt+Enter) and give permissions to the account Oracle service uses, put your file into that directory, recreate directory object in Oracle: `CREATE DIRECTORY EXAMPLE_DIR AS 'C:\EXT`. Then try again your code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY EXAMPLE_DIR AS 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop';
GRANT ALL ON DIRECTORY EXAMPLE_DIR TO PUBLIC;
```